# How to use JSession ID in subsequent request as cookie in request header

Tags: jmeter

I am developing a JMeter script which is similar to the following :

```
Test Plan
    HTTP Cookie Manager
    Login - Thread Group
    Search - Thread Group
```

One of the Login samplers has Set-Cookie in the response headers which is in the form of JSession Ids like :

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx;
```

This cookie is used in Request Headers of subsequent requests. Challenge that I am facing now is I am able to extract the cookie from login sampler response header but how am I supposed to use this in subsequent threads groups.
I have even set CookieManager.save.cookies=true in the properties file.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have [`CookieManager.save.cookies=true`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) in your [user.properties file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and restarted JMeter after that you should be able to access the cookie value where needed as:

```
${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}
```

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)